# Using numpy dstack elementwise?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm aware that dstack can do this:

```
array([0, 1, 2])
array([3, 4, 5])
```

to:

```
array([[[0,3], 
        [1,4], 
        [2,5]]]
```

But I want this without looping:

```
array([[[0,3],
        [0,4],
        [0,5],
        [1,3],
        [1,4],
        [1,5],
        [2,3],
        [2,4],
        [2,5]]])
```

Is it possible? It's like a many to many relationship and I know I can do with pandas, but would there be a simpler and more straight way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `np.repeat` and `np.tile` methods do what you want.

```
x = np.array( [0,1,2] )
y = np.array( [3,4,5] )
z = np.dstack( (np.repeat(x,3), np.tile(y,3) ) )
>>> print z
array([[[0, 3],
        [0, 4],
        [0, 5],
        [1, 3],
        [1, 4],
        [1, 5],
        [2, 3],
        [2, 4],
        [2, 5]]])
```